# Android pass a single string from a Fragment to Asynctask

Tags: android, string, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I would like to pass a String from an Editext inside a Fragment into an asynctask, how I can do that? I have read here similar posts but I'm doing something wrong.

Fragment

```
        EditText txt=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textSearch);
        EditText date=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);


        // Get Editext string and pass it to the Asynctask
        txtSearch = txt.getEditableText().toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "variabile text " + txtSearch);
        new TessAsyncEngine().execute(txtSearch);
```

Asynctask (go to //detect words)

```
public class TessAsyncEngine extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    static final String TAG = "DBG_" + TessAsyncEngine.class.getName();

    private Bitmap bmp;

    private Activity context;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

        try {

            if(params.length < 2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error passing parameter to execute - missing params");
                return null;
            }

            if(!(params[0] instanceof Activity) || !(params[1] instanceof Bitmap)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error passing parameter to execute(context, bitmap)");
                //Log.e(TAG, "Error passing parameter " + params[0].toString() + params[1].toString());
                return null;
            }

            context = (Activity)params[0];

            bmp = (Bitmap)params[1];

            if(context == null || bmp == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error passed null parameter to execute(context, bitmap)");
                return null;
            }

            int rotate = 0;

            if(params.length == 3 && params[2]!= null && params[2] instanceof Integer){
                rotate = (Integer) params[2];
            }

            if(rotate >= -180 && rotate <= 180 && rotate != 0)
            {
                bmp = Tools.preRotateBitmap(bmp, rotate);
                Log.d(TAG, "Rotated OCR bitmap " + rotate + " degrees");
            }

            TessEngine tessEngine =  TessEngine.Generate(context);

            bmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            String result = tessEngine.detectText(bmp);

            //detect words
            String textSearch = new ScanFragment().txtSearch;


            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase(textSearch)) {
                String result1 = ("Warning!: ") + result.concat(" found");
                return result1;
            } else {
                String result2 = ("I have found: ") + result.concat(" check it");
                return result2;
            }
            //Log.d(TAG, result);

            //return result;


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + ex + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        if(s == null || bmp == null || context == null)
            return;

        ImageDialog.New()
                .addBitmap(bmp)
                .addTitle(s)
                .show(context.getFragmentManager(), TAG);

        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to add the trace

```
08-25 10:41:25.210 6311-7176/com.fastnetserv.app D/DBG_com.fastnetserv.app.TessAsyncEngine: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                            Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
```

EDIT2 AsyncTask after Ashish suggestions

```
public class TessAsyncEngine extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    static final String TAG = "DBG_" + TessAsyncEngine.class.getName();

    private Bitmap bmp;

    private Activity context;

    String search;

    TessAsyncEngine(String search){
        this.search=search;
    }

    @Override
    //protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){

        try {

            if(params.length < 2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error passing parameter to execute - missing params");
                return null;
            }

            if(!(params[0] instanceof Activity) || !(params[1] instanceof Bitmap)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error passing parameter to execute(context, bitmap)");
                //Log.e(TAG, "Error passing parameter " + params[0].toString() + params[1].toString());
                return null;
            }

            context = (Activity)params[0];

            bmp = (Bitmap)params[1];

            if(context == null || bmp == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error passed null parameter to execute(context, bitmap)");
                return null;
            }

            int rotate = 0;

            if(params.length == 3 && params[2]!= null && params[2] instanceof Integer){
                rotate = (Integer) params[2];
            }

            if(rotate >= -180 && rotate <= 180 && rotate != 0)
            {
                bmp = Tools.preRotateBitmap(bmp, rotate);
                Log.d(TAG, "Rotated OCR bitmap " + rotate + " degrees");
            }

            TessEngine tessEngine =  TessEngine.Generate(context);

            bmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            String result = tessEngine.detectText(bmp);
            //detect words
            //Bundle bundle = context.getIntent().getExtras();
            //String txtSearch = bundle.getString("TextSearch");
            String textSearch = new ScanFragment().txtSearch;



            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase(textSearch)) {
                String result1 = ("WARNING! : ") + result.concat(" found");
                return result1;
            } else {
                String result2 = ("detected this word: ") + result.concat(" please check it");
                return result2;
            }
            //Log.d(TAG, result);

            //return result;


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + ex + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        if(s == null || bmp == null || context == null)
            return;

        ImageDialog.New()
                .addBitmap(bmp)
                .addTitle(s)
                .show(context.getFragmentManager(), TAG);

        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

CameraFragmnet

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, View.OnClickListener,
        Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.ShutterCallback {

    static final String TAG = "DBG_" + MainActivity.class.getName();

    Button shutterButton;
    Button focusButton;
    FocusBoxView focusBox;
    SurfaceView cameraFrame;
    CameraEngine cameraEngine;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public CameraFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment CameraFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static CameraFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        CameraFragment fragment = new CameraFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    // Camera Code

    public String detectText(Bitmap bitmap) {

        TessDataManager.initTessTrainedData(getActivity());
        TessBaseAPI tessBaseAPI = new TessBaseAPI();

        //String path = "/mnt/sdcard/com.fastnetserv.app/tessdata/eng.traineddata";
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/com.fastnetserv.app/files/tesseract/tessdata/eng.traineddata";


        Log.d(TAG, "Check data path: " + path);

        tessBaseAPI.setDebug(true);
        tessBaseAPI.init(path, "ita"); //Init the Tess with the trained data file, with english language

        //For example if we want to only detect numbers
        //Already defined on TessEngine
        //tessBaseAPI.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "1234567890");
        //tessBaseAPI.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST, "!@#$%^&*()_+=-qwertyuiop[]}{POIU" +
        //        "YTREWQasdASDfghFGHjklJKLl;L:'\"\\|~`xcvXCVbnmBNM,./<>?");


        tessBaseAPI.setImage(bitmap);

        String text = tessBaseAPI.getUTF8Text();

        //Log.d(TAG, "Got data: " + result);
        tessBaseAPI.end();

        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Surface Created - starting camera");

        if (cameraEngine != null && !cameraEngine.isOn()) {
            cameraEngine.start();
        }

        if (cameraEngine != null && cameraEngine.isOn()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera engine already on");
            return;
        }

        cameraEngine = CameraEngine.New(holder);
        cameraEngine.start();

        Log.d(TAG, "Camera engine started");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        cameraFrame = (SurfaceView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.camera_frame);
        shutterButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.shutter_button);
        focusBox = (FocusBoxView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.focus_box);
        focusButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.focus_button);

        shutterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        focusButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = cameraFrame.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        cameraFrame.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (cameraEngine != null && cameraEngine.isOn()) {
            cameraEngine.stop();
        }

        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = cameraFrame.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.removeCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == shutterButton){
            if(cameraEngine != null && cameraEngine.isOn()){
                cameraEngine.takeShot(this, this, this);
            }
        }

        if(v == focusButton){
            if(cameraEngine!=null && cameraEngine.isOn()){
                cameraEngine.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Picture taken");

        if (data == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got null data");
            return;
        }

        Bitmap bmp = Tools.getFocusedBitmap(getActivity(), camera, data, focusBox.getBox());

        Log.d(TAG, "Got bitmap");

        //new TessAsyncEngine().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, this, bmp);
        new TessAsyncEngine().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, getActivity(), bmp);

    }

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {

    }

}
```

Comment: You are passing just one parameter to AsyncTask. So the first `if` condition in `doInBackground` becomes true and it return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can also pass in constructor of Async Task.
    private string;
    public TessAsyncEngine(String string)
    {
    this.string = string;
    }

Comment: new TessAsyncEngine(txtSearch).execute();

Comment: now I got this error "CameraFragment.java Error:(239, 9) error: constructor TessAsyncEngine in class TessAsyncEngine cannot be applied to given types; required: String found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Comment: AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>

Comment: With "AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>" I receive the error  "Class TessAsyncEngine must be either declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(Params...)"

Comment: protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) this will work i don't think you require anything in return and do AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>

Comment: Done but this generate a lot of "Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.Void' to 'android.app.Activity'" and and error with "super.onPostExecute(s);"

Comment: i have also used it and working fine. Can u post your complete code here after chnages.

Comment: Sure! I have added it into the first post, please see "EDIT2" thanks!

Comment: dude how can cast Void params to Activity and the next line is also wrong typecasting bmp just pass all the params in the constructor method of your AsyncTask.

Comment: ok, how I can do that for Objects? I have also attached the CameraFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to the Asynctask:

```
public class TessAsyncEngine extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    static final String TAG = "DBG_" + TessAsyncEngine.class.getName();

    private Bitmap bmp;

    private Activity context;
    String search;

    TessAsyncEngine(String search)
   {
      this.search=search;
   } 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

        try {

            if(params.length < 2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error passing parameter to execute - missing params");
                return null;
            }

            if(!(params[0] instanceof Activity) || !(params[1] instanceof Bitmap)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error passing parameter to execute(context, bitmap)");
                //Log.e(TAG, "Error passing parameter " + params[0].toString() + params[1].toString());
                return null;
            }

            context = (Activity)params[0];

            bmp = (Bitmap)params[1];

            if(context == null || bmp == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error passed null parameter to execute(context, bitmap)");
                return null;
            }

            int rotate = 0;

            if(params.length == 3 && params[2]!= null && params[2] instanceof Integer){
                rotate = (Integer) params[2];
            }

            if(rotate >= -180 && rotate <= 180 && rotate != 0)
            {
                bmp = Tools.preRotateBitmap(bmp, rotate);
                Log.d(TAG, "Rotated OCR bitmap " + rotate + " degrees");
            }

            TessEngine tessEngine =  TessEngine.Generate(context);

            bmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            String result = tessEngine.detectText(bmp);

            //detect words
            String textSearch = new ScanFragment().txtSearch;


            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase(textSearch)) {
                String result1 = ("Warning!: ") + result.concat(" found");
                return result1;
            } else {
                String result2 = ("I have found: ") + result.concat(" check it");
                return result2;
            }
            //Log.d(TAG, result);

            //return result;


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + ex + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        if(s == null || bmp == null || context == null)
            return;

        ImageDialog.New()
                .addBitmap(bmp)
                .addTitle(s)
                .show(context.getFragmentManager(), TAG);

        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

Call the asynctask like this:

```
 new TessAsyncEngine(txtSearch).execute();
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried your suggestion but now I got this error "\CameraFragment.java
Error:(239, 9) error: constructor TessAsyncEngine in class TessAsyncEngine cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"